# How do you use the console to annex one country to another?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

I just want to mess around in HOI3 using the console. In particular, I want to see what happens if I unite central Europe under Poland. The wiki says that using the `surrender TAG + TAG` command should do it. But the game says that command doesn't exist when I try to do it. Additionally, when I type "help" I get "no help for you!". It would be funny if I didn't want to actually do something. How do you actually get one country to annex another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in many Paradox games, to be able to use the console, you have to launch the game with the following parameters :

`-debug -debugscripts`

In Steam, you can right-click on the game, select "Set launch options" and enter that here.